# RTK-Query Auto-Caching doesn't work with "add" functionality

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to Redux-Toolkit an RTK-Query. Therefore I wanted to build a simple CRUD-Product Website. After setting up the Store, my ApiSlice and a productSlice with the following Code:

```
import { api } from "./apiSlice";

export const produktApiSlice = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    produkte: builder.query({
      query: () => "produkte",
      providesTags: () => ["Produkte"],
    }),
    produktHinzufügen: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: "produkte/",
        method: "POST",
        body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Produkte"],
    }),
    produktLöschen: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `produkte/${id}`,
        method: "DELETE",
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Produkte"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useProdukteQuery,
  useProduktHinzufügenMutation,
  useProduktLöschenMutation,
} = produktApiSlice;
```

My Frontend gets automatically updated when deleting a Product with the "produktLöschen"-Mutation. But adding a Product with my "produktHinzufügen"-Mutation always needs a page refresh for showing.

I do not unterstand the difference between deleting and adding a post. Both Queries use invalidatesTags: ["Produkte“] but adding a Product just seems not to refresh the cache.

I tried to remove the body data from "produktHinzufügen". As this being the only recognizable difference between the "produktHinzufügen" and "produktLöschen" queries I hoped to get the caching work.

Thank you in Advance!